# How to use firebase only for signed in users

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, sharedpreferences

I want to create a basic app for android with firebase. For better user experience I want the users to be able to use the app without signing in. In this case, the user data should be stored only locally (e.g. in shared preferences and not be uploaded to firebase). One way would be to create a separate logic for both use cases, and switch between them. (Maybe in the startup watch if the user == null). But is there an easier way built into firebase, because it feels like this should be a common use-case?

Comment: If you want the data locally, you will have to manage that switching yourself, and switch your data store from Firebase to something like Room or SQLite when they are logged out. Alternately, you can use [anonymous sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) with Firebase, so they can use it without signing in but still store their data in the cloud, then choose to create an account and sign-in later if they want.

Comment: Firebase is an online first database - it's core usage is to have an online experience. If a majority of what you're doing is offline first, Firebase may not be the best solution, unless you want to craft code to handle that as @TylerV mentions above. You may want to take a look at [MongoDB Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/introduction/) if this is a mostly offline first use case.